# Hidden fragment to isolate code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My question is how custom it is to isolate certain functionality required by an activity into a hidden fragment, in this case Location Services.

My initial thought was to pass the boilerplate callbacks that are related to Location Services into a separate plain Java utility class, and only keep the listener for `onLocationChanged`in the Activity. This would be much cleaner.
The problem is that this results in circular dependencies, because the pojo would require a reference to the activity context for certain calls, and the Activity would have a reference to the utility class resulting in a circular dependency, which results in tight coupling.

Therefore my thought was to make a hidden fragment and store the code there; this would keep the code in the main activity clean.
What is the usual way to do this?

The current code that I use:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{
    private static final String TAG = "HOME_ACTIVITY"; // Logging

    private GoogleApiClient     mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location            mLocation;
    private LocationManager     mLocationManager;
    private LocationRequest     mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;

    private double mLatCurLoc;
    private double mLngCurLoc;

    private float  MIN_DISTANCE = 200.0f;
    private long   UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long   FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Android Studio complains that we should check the permissions before getting last location
        // However, we have already checked permissions in the previous activity
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatCurLoc = location.getLatitude();
        mLngCurLoc = location.getLongitude();
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Log.i("LOCATION_CHANGED", msg);
    }


}
```

Comment: Won't inheritance be much cleaner architecture? The moment you no longer need locations functionality then just change the parent class. Or if other activity also need locations - just extend the same super class.

Comment: @azizbekian Sounds like a nice option. Our app depends on Location Services to work, so inheritance should be a possibility. I have the tendency to avoid inheritance overall, but in this case I assume it can be different.

Comment: Will post as an answer. Maybe somebody would suggest something more suitable, we'll see.

Comment: There's pro and cons about inheritance. There's a nice discussion here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/why-avoid-java-inheritance-extends. I'd go with composition instead of inheritance. But regarding your problem, it's personal preference. Your class is clean and short (there could be some clean ups actually, the empty if block hurts :P, and it's a bit too long for my taste) and can be refactored very easily in the future - always question the 'beauty' of the class when you change it in the future.

Comment: @slowy Yes of course, it is still in demo mode atm. The app has a dependency on location services (the core concept of the app breaks without it), so inheritance in this case would be a good fit. I guess that I could achieve composition using callbacks or promises, but the inheritance proposition works well for me and is much simpler for its purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the beauty of inheritance in OOP. You'd just have an activity which will deal with location services, and make your other activities who want to deal with locations extend e.g. `LocationAwareActivity`. The moment one of those activities is not interested in locations you'd just change the parent class, and vice versa, the moment one of your activities would like to be aware of locations - it will extend `LocationAwareActivity`.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm so used to avoiding inheritance because of tight coupling that I didn't see it as an option anymore. But clear use case here imo. Well done!